# What is break down of amps on household usages plugin,lights ect

Tags: electrical

Looking for information on how much amps are used for plug ins,light switches,ect

Answer (score 1):

Switches do not use any power at all. The things they switch use power. Lights use whatever the wattage of the lamps (bulbs) are in the fixtures. Things that are plugged in use basically what's on the rating plate.

You can find many many web sites listing estimates of what household appliances, etc draw while in use. A quick Google search will bring lots of info. Also, most utility web sites have good information about using generators. Typically this includes average appliance power consumption charts.